# GCC __func__ gets evaluated to an empty string

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, string-literals

Given the following code in a project I'm working on:

```
/* Pre-definitions in a pre-definitions file to be included in the project */
#ifdef  WIN32
#define __FUNCNAME__ __FUNCTION__
#else
#define __FUNCNAME__ __func__  
#endif

/* My definitions */
#define MAC() \
     MAC1()

#define MAC1() \
     myPrintFunction(__FUNCNAME__)

/* My print function */
void myPrintFunction(const char * functionName)
{
     printf("\n func name: %s \n",functionName);
}

/* Macro usage example function */
void myFunction()
{
     if (some_condition)
     {
         MAC();
     }
}
```

The function name is presented as an empty string.
Any idea why, and how can I fix it?

Code compiled and tested on Linux machine, using GCC compiler.

Comment: Are you sure that `some_condition` is true?

Comment: No `main()`? Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes I am sure. I can see the "\n func name: \n" and I'm also debugging this code with a debugger and that code is being executed.

Comment: (1) What happens if you replace `MAC()` with `myPrintFunction(__FUNCNAME__)` in the source code? (2) Do you actually have the definitions of `MAC` and `MAC1` written as shown, with a line break in between name and (intended) definition, and _without_ a backslash at the end of the `#define` line?

Comment: Work correctly for me (OSX LLVM)

Comment: It could be the case the `__func__` is expanded on the first pass...

Comment: @EugeneSh. `__func__` is not a macro.

Comment: @zwol Right. So in C99 it should work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `__func__` out of the box. It's been part of the C standard since C99. Change your compiler settings to use at least that standard.

Note that `__func__` is *not* a macro but a *predefined identifier* which takes the form such that writing it anywhere within a function body is exactly equivalent to using it at that point, having first written

`static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`

just after the opening brace of a function body.

Formally the behaviour of your current code is *undefined*. Any symbol containing two consecutive underscores is reserved by the system. (That includes macro names, function names, and variable names.)

Comment: I think you meant to say "Any *macro name* containing two consecutive underscores...".

Comment: Sorry I meant it to be even stronger: macro name, function name, and variable name

Comment: @TobySpeight: Then what if I name a local variable `int __func__`?

Comment: @Bathsheba: And type names, and member names and `struct`/`union`/`enum` tags :-) - I think the term which covers all is "identifier".

Comment: @AndyG you would be *mad* to do that. Leading underscores are reserved.

Comment: @AndyG: the code in the question didn't have a non-conforming variable name, but did have a non-conforming macro name.  Mentioning the other kinds of identifier that mustn't contain double underscore obviously improves the answer, and that's what Bathsheba has done (and what I expected in response to my slightly tongue-in-cheek comment).

Comment: To be clear, the OP's code has undefined behavior because (and _only_ because) it defines a macro named `__FUNCNAME__`, which is in the reserved namespace.  _Using_ identifiers in the reserved namespace that are documented has, at worst, implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as presented gives the expected result (once I'd added the necessary includes and main):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef  WIN32
#define __FUNCNAME__ __FUNCTION__
#else
#define __FUNCNAME__ __func__  
#endif

/* My definitions */
#define MAC() \
     MAC1()

#define MAC1() \
     myPrintFunction(__FUNCNAME__)

void myPrintFunction(const char * functionName)
{
     printf("\n func name: %s \n",functionName);
}

int main()
{
    MAC();
}
```

I compiled this using `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` with no warnings.

You should really post a complete (but minimal) example that actually compiles, along with the compiler flags you used, as something must certainly be different to explain the symptoms you describe.

Also, when writing statements as macros, you may find it helpful to use the `do {...} while (0)` idiom to avoid unexpected expansions changing the control flow.